Lenient matching on repeating digits in Solr search
I have Solr documents that need to provide some leniency on repeating character matches in specific cases. As an example, I have inputs such as these which currently have their numbers tokenized with a minimum length of 3 characters:
ABC1-123-456 => [1123, 1123456, 123, 123456, 456]
ABC1-10000 => [110000, 110000, 10000]
What I would like is to better handle repeating numbers such as in the second case. The real world cases have up to 7 repeating numbers, so the user is very likely to miss a zero or two and will receive no match.
Specifically, if I end up with a token such as 7200000 with, say, 3 or more repeating numbers, have that tokenized as [7200, 72000, ...]
Is this something that's practical with out-of-box Solr filters, or am I better off creating a custom filter?

You can use a pattern replace filter: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/filters.html#pattern-replace-filter to remove any digit that repeats three or more times with just three copies of the same digit. There is no need to store all the varying tokens if you perform the same replacement on the query side (i.e. 7200000 would be just indexed as 7200 (or 72000, depending on which behavior you want when actually searching for 7200).

Ah, that's a good idea. I'll give that a try.
